# How to make dictionary out of complex column of dataset?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

So I have this column = Test_Label in my dataset. (See Screenshot 1 to see part of the column)
[image]

I'm trying to make a dictionary for each row. 
My desired list, I believe should look like this for each row

For example. Below is my column.

```
1                                                                                                  None
2                                                                                                  None
3                                                                                                  None
4                                                                                                  None
5                                                                              COMP=off,CONTROLLER=4310
6                                                                       TEMP=25,SOAK=15,CONTROLLER=4310
7                                                                                         DSA=1,HSDIG=0
8                    VBAT=3.00,BGSEL=typ,CMON=none,POWER_MODE=buck,REVISION=ac,TEST=copy_settings,CS=bb
9                                                                  REVISION=ac,TEST=copy_settings,CS=bb
13                                                                 REVISION=ac,TEST=copy_settings,CS=bb
```

Here is a list I just created out of my data. I think this will help to copy to IDE.

```
[['None'],
 ['None'],
 ['None'],
 ['COMP=off,CONTROLLER=4310'],
 ['TEMP=25,SOAK=15,CONTROLLER=4310'],
 ['DSA=1,HSDIG=0'],
 ['VBAT=3.00,BGSEL=typ,CMON=none,POWER_MODE=buck,REVISION=ac,TEST=copy_settings,CS=bb'],
 ['REVISION=ac,TEST=copy_settings,CS=bb'],
 ['REVISION=ac,TEST=copy_settings,CS=bb']]
```

for the above column, my desired dictionary would something look like this for each row.

```
{'None': 1}
{'None': 1}
{'None': 1}
{'COMP': 'off', 'CONTROLLER'=4310}
{'TEMP': 25, 'SOAK' : 15,'CONTROLLER' :4310 }
{'REVISION': 'ac', 'TEST':'copy_settings','CS':'bb' }
{'REVISION': 'ac', 'TEST':'copy_settings','CS':'bb' }
```

Though, I'm not able to create my dict like above.
I'm also posting my code here.

```
# Create an empty list 
Row_list =[] 

# Iterate over each row 
for rows in Dataframe.itertuples(): 
    # Create list for the current row 
    my_list =[rows.Test_Label] 
    # append the list to the final list 
    Row_list.append(my_list) 


res = []
for list in Row_list:
    res.append(str(list[0]).split(','))


new = []
for l in res:
    new.append([x.split('=') for x in l)        
new
A2 = [(element + [1])[:7] for element in new]
A2
dict(A2)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Can someone help me out with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a function to parse each row and then `apply` that function to each row.

```
def custom_parse(row):
    if not row or row == 'None':
        return {'None': 1}
    else:
        split = row.split(',')
        out = {}
        for item in split:
            k, v = item.split('=')
            out[k] = v
        return out

df['a'].apply(custom_parse)

1                                           {'None': 1}
2                                           {'None': 1}
3                                           {'None': 1}
4                                           {'None': 1}
5                 {'COMP': 'off', 'CONTROLLER': '4310'}
6     {'SOAK': '15', 'TEMP': '25', 'CONTROLLER': '43...
7                            {'HSDIG': '0', 'DSA': '1'}
8     {'REVISION': 'ac', 'CS': 'bb', 'VBAT': '3.00',...
9     {'REVISION': 'ac', 'CS': 'bb', 'TEST': 'copy_s...
13    {'REVISION': 'ac', 'CS': 'bb', 'TEST': 'copy_s...
```

Comment: Hey, Thank you so much, I understand your code. I have still one small query, what happened if any of my row has key but not a value for the dictionary.
For example
```
COMP,CONTROLLER=4310

```

Above I don't have any value for key comp.


Thanks again

Comment: so what should the value be if it isn’t present? also if you _understand_ the code it should be relatively easy for you to modify it and add the extra conditional, correct?